# How to remove HTML anchor tag in email body of Lotus Notes by programming

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm trying to remove a link totally from an email body. I have no idea how by treating body as MIME entity. But I did try for a while in the body as rich text. Here is part of my codes:

```
RichTextNavigator nav = body.createNavigator();
RichTextRange range = body.createRange();
nav.findFIrstString("theLinkToBeRemoved");
range.setBegin(nav);
range.setEnd(nav);
range.remove();
```

But only the body inside anchor tags has been removed. For example:

```
<a href="http://google.ca">google</a>
```

actually becomes

```
<a href="http://google.ca"></a>
```

after processing and sending email.

My question is how to remove the anchor tags completely. Thanks!

Comment: Was the message created in MIME format or Rich Text? If it was created as MIME, then I think you will have better luck working with it as MIME.

Comment: It's created in Rich Text. But I can convert the document to MIME format. I know how to stream an HTML text to MIME body. But is there a way to do the opposite thing, getting HTML format text from MIME body or Rich Text body? If so, it would be the best solution and quite straightforward because every modification can be done on HTML .

Comment: Have you looked at the NotesMIMEntity class (just MimeEntity in the Java classes) and its method getContentAsText()?

Comment: Yes. The weird thing is for an existing Document, I can't call createMIMEEntity or getMIMEEntity of Document.  createMIMEEntity will tell me item body is already created. And getMIMEEntity returns null. And also, getContentAsText() can print anchor tag, but not bold, italic or other decoration tag for text. Texts are just printed as plain text. I expect wrappers like <b>, <i>.

Comment: I found an interest project which should be able to solve my problem: https://code.google.com/p/lnrt2html/

Comment: It seems to me that DXL would be the easiest way of going about this; it should be just a matter of GetElementsByTagName and a (possibly recursive) RemoveChild. You even have the option of retaining the text while removing the link, if that's useful.

Comment: Thank you Stan! DXL seems the perfect solution in my case. Could you post an answer that in general describes how to use it to convert the rich text body, and then take the changes into effect in my email and send? So that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also try with the *FindFirstElement* method of the *RichTextNavigator* class, looking for an element of type *RichTextItem.RTELEM_TYPE_DOCLINK* ?

Hmmm... I wonder, why do you need to remove links... It sounds like a managerial issue that's solved programmatically.

Comment: He's not looking for doclinks.

Comment: I think it's not a doclink as it links to an HTTP address of another website. I have also tried FindFirstElement. But when it comes to modification of contents we have to use RichTextRange. So the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found a beautiful solution: [code.google.com/p/lnrt2html](http://code.google.com/p/lnrt2html)

It  achieves the trick of conversion from rich text to html, rather than dxl/xml. And then we have many options to parse html data, such as Jsoup. After that, use this method to input your html string stream to MIMEEntity and send: [MIMEEntity - setContentFromText](http://domino1.qtzar.com/lotus.domino/lotus/domino/MIMEEntity.html#setContentFromText(lotus.domino.Stream,%20java.lang.String,%20int))